# What does it mean, "Vine strike's still loose"?

Tags: avatar

In *Avatar* (2009) extended version, Jake, who is in his wheelchair, meets Trudy in a large hall with weapons:

> Trudy: Hey, Wainﬂeet! Get it done! We bounce at zero-nine.
>
> Wainﬂeet: Yeah, I'm on it, capitaine!
>
> Trudy: **Vine strike's still loose**.
>
> Jake: You guys are packing some heavy gear.

What does it mean, "Vine strike's still loose"?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just for some additional context, where is that text coming from? Is it just what you think you are are hearing or a subtitle? Also, take a minute and take our [tour] and visit the [help] to see what SFF.SE is all about.

Comment: Text copied from Subtitles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trudy's [Scorpion Gunship](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion_Gunship) has '*vine-strike cutters*' designed to cut through vines that get in the way of the craft. She is presumably referring to one of these being loose.

[image]

An [earlier version of the official "Pandorapedia" site](https://web.archive.org/web/20100427144033/http://www.pandorapedia.com:80/scorpion_gunship) has this to say on the subject.

> ... ballistic ceramics and carbon-nanotube composites in the rotor duct-rings [that] protect the rotors...

and that

> ... These ducts are quite robust, and can withstand significant impacts. They also prevent the rotor blade tips from contacting obstacles when the aircraft is operating in complex environments. This makes the aircraft ideal for flight ops amongst the dangling vines of the Pandoran rainforest and amongst the floating mountains. **Special “vine-strike” cutters have been added to the leading edges of the airframe and the rotor ducts. These guide any impacting vines into a cutting notch,** much like the wire-strike kits which have been employed on rotorcraft on Earth for two centuries.

Note that the [article on the current version of the site](https://www.avatar.com/pandorapedia/scorpion-gunship) doesn't carry this information.

Comment: Wow. Once I started editing this, I just couldn't stop. I don't think there's a need for the wiki article at all, since you've found and quoted the primary source.